# Error in reading excel in flutter using excel package

Tags: flutter, flutter-exception

Code:

```
filename = "xls_path/sample.xlsx";
final File file = File(filename);
List<int> bytes = file.readAsBytesSync(); (Getting below error in this line)
var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes.toList());
```

Extract of package:excel/src/sheet/header_footer.dart:193:5

```
extension BoolParsing on String {
bool parseBool() 

 {
        if (this.toLowerCase() == 'true') {
        return true;
 } else if (this.toLowerCase() == 'false') {
       return false;
 }

    throw '"$this" can not be parsed to boolean.';

  }
}
```

Error: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: "0" can not be parsed to boolean.
E/flutter ( 5250): #0      BoolParsing.parseBool (package:excel/src/sheet/header_footer.dart:193:5)
E/flutter ( 5250): #1      HeaderFooter.fromXmlElement (package:excel/src/sheet/header_footer.dart:169:67)
E/flutter

( 5250): #2      Parser._parseHeaderFooter (package:excel/src/parser/parse.dart:696:45)
E/flutter ( 5250): #3      Parser._parseTable (package:excel/src/parser/parse.dart:439:5)
E/flutter ( 5250): #4      Parser._parseContent.<anonymous closure> (package:excel/src/parser/parse.dart:160:9)
E/flutter ( 5250): #5      Iterable.forEach (dart:core/iterable.dart:325:35)
E/flutter ( 5250): #6      Parser._parseContent (package:excel/src/parser/parse.dart:158:39)
E/flutter ( 5250): #7      Parser.*startParsing (package:excel/src/parser/parse.dart:18:5)
E/flutter ( 5250): #8      new Excel.* (package:excel/src/excel.dart:74:12)
E/flutter ( 5250): #9      _newExcel (package:excel/src/excel.dart:17:20)

I have tried reading already existing excel workbook and append new rows to the sheet and save it.
Package used excel: ^2.0.1, excel: ^2.0.0-null-safety-3.

I expect to read and save with new data using flutter excel package.

Comment: are you trying to load from assets?

Comment: Trying to read excel from /storage/emulated/0/Myfolder/Sample.xlsx

Comment: can't my code help you? can more code snippets provided?

Comment: After running flutter clean run and restart of app it started working without any change of code.

Answer (score -1):

- Use the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) plugin to get the storage path of ios/android
- like this

```
  Future<Directory?> getLocalDirectory() async {
    return Platform.isAndroid
        ? await path.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        : await path.getApplicationSupportDirectory();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. After running flutter clean run and restart of app it started working without any change of code.

Comment: Doubtful on the flutter clean, I tried but didn’t work out.